# Installing old uploaded APK from Google Play Console not working anymore?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I used to test migration problems via installing old APKs from google play console and then updating to the most recent internal test version.

Since at least a week this doesn't work anymore. Every share link to a specific APK just links me to the latest APK that is published. I'm talking about this share link:
[image]

So either the live production version, or as an internal tester the current internal test version.

Anyone else has this problem? I couldn't find anything about it online.

My personal fix now is to manually download the APK, install it via ADB and then update via playstore. But that's of course more annoying than just clicking a link.

Answer (score 1):

I have been in contact with an agent from google for more than 1 month about this issue, first they insisted that it was not a problem, but I helped them to understand this issue with a few images. The agent who took care of me says that their technical team has been investigating this issue for a while.

It seems we have to wait until we get a proper fix. Until that, you can use this area to upload your apk and get a specific link for that:
https://play.google.com/console/u/0/internal-app-sharing
This part gave google play link for that build and still working on android devices without a problem.

Best!